# Android Studio shows error on startup if android build tools v0.6.1 are used

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-build

After updating gradle dependency of android build tools to 0.6.1

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1'
}
```

this error appears on every ide startup

> Problems importing/refreshing Gradle project 'ProjectName':
>            Unable to find a JDK 1.6 installed.
>            After configuring a suitable JDK in the Project Structure dialog, sync the Gradle project again.

Error is shown on different projects and both on Windows/Ubuntu with latest jdk+jre 7

If come back to previous versions all is fine

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

Why new android tools need deprecated jdk? And how to avoid this error not installing old jdk?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: And what? Android Studio 0.2.11 and gradle 1.8 installed, and this problem is different from one pointed out in known issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. Details here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60724